# Medicaid legal criteria on a persons physical condition

Tags: medical

To begin, I am looking for specific legal criteria for Medicaid in Pennsylvania or with the Federal government regarding a persons physical assessment/qualification for Medicaid and not financial qualification.

*To be clear, I am not trying to determine eligability, that is already determined though not legally, however, in doing my research, I failed to book mark specifics I now need to provide proper care for my Mother.*

Background: In the past few short years, my Mother's health has taken a serious turn for the worst. Mom suffers from tremors, mild dimentia, depression/anxiety. These have devastating effects that includes inability to pay bills, manage finances, take medication reliably, drink enough water or other fluids, feed herself, make adequate decisions (at times), recall important information, make and keep appointments, perform standard housekeeping tasks, maintain and manage her dogs, etc. As well, she has fallen down the stairs and had spent 5 days in the hospital, has had several visits to the emergency room due to issues with eating, drinking, medications, etc. She no longer drives. She also often sleeps long into the day as late as 1:45pm when I have woken her up effecting her medications, eating, etc. She has trouble doing laundry in a timely manner. Her tremors makes it impossible for her to write. She in not able to communicate adequately her condition with her physicians. She is not able to maintain her personal possessions. She often falls off of the toilet and cannot get up easily even with support. She also occasionally remembers things that never happened or happened a long time ago as if it were today.

Motivation: My mother has several doctors most of whom are within the same HMO providing care for her through Medicare. Her one psychiatrist is not a member of that group. Her GP is a newly minted doctor and is adequate for most things, however, and I am sorry to say this, she can be a colossal idiot at odd times. Mom's medical care is primarily stove-piped where each doctor only addresses the issues that pertain to their specific level of care. The problem is that no-one doctor has a full view of all of the issues. I have to obtain an options assessment (care plan) which is traditionally provided by the GP who theoretically sits at the center of Moms care. However, as stated, I do not trust her ability to fully assess Moms conditions especially since much of it rests with her other doctors.

My questions are this:

1] Where can I find the legal physical requirements for Medicaid as I have outlined for the state of Pennsylvania or at the Federal level that applies?

2] Is it reasonable to ask her psychiatrist and not the GP for an options assessment?

I have found:

http://www.pacode.com/secure/data/055/chapter52/chap52toc.html

*(abbreviated)*

```
CHAPTER 52. LONG-TERM LIVING HOME AND COMMUNITY-BASED SERVICES

§ 52.3. Definitions.

ADL—Activities of daily living—The term includes eating, drinking, ambulating, transferring in and out of a bed or chair, toileting, bladder and bowel management, personal hygiene, self-administering medication and proper turning and positioning in a bed or chair.

Critical incident—An occurrence of an event that jeopardizes the participant’s health or welfare including:

(vii)   Medication errors that result in hospitalization, an emergency room visit or other medical intervention.

IADL—Instrumental activities of daily living—The term includes the following activities when done on behalf of a participant:

(i)    Laundry.
(ii)   Shopping.
(iii)  Securing and using transportation.
(iv)   Using a telephone.
(v)    Making and keeping appointments.
(vi)   Caring for personal possessions.
(vii)  Writing correspondence.
(viii) Using a prosthetic device.
(ix)   Housekeeping.
```

This applies to ADL (activities of daily living) and not the full view of physical requirements. As well, this is only a definition and a bit fuzzy. All criteria I have seen the last two days so far is fuzzy. Clearly this is not the full criteria. I have tried many of the obvious sites to no avail. I had at one point found an excellent article written by an attorney where the exact details and links to the law were provided. However, I did not bookmark the page/site and cannot seem to find it again. I have spent two full days without success on just getting one or more bullet lists that I can use to properly communicate issues with Mom's doctors and achieving a properly designed care plan that can be submitted for Medicaid.

As I said, clearly Mom's conditions will be accepted by Medicaid. Finances is not my concern since that is already handled. I just want to properly manage the criteria list through the full process of herding cats (I mean coordinating doctors input to a proper and adequate result).